# GLSL/C++: Default behavior from custom shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have some GLSL shaders that are compiling correctly, and being successfully attached to a program that links correctly. I have confirmed that other shaders work properly in my program. The strange thing is that the result I see seems to be the same behavior I would get out of default shaders (color, no lighting).

I will paste the source code of both the vertex and fragment shaders, as well as all excerpts from my C++ source code that pertain to the shaders. I will explain in comments any functions or classes that are unique to my program.

My vertex shader (contained in "dirlight.vs")

```
uniform int lightcount;
uniform vec4 lightdirs[];
uniform vec4 lightdifs[];
uniform vec4 lightambs[];
uniform vec4 lightposs[];

void main()
{
    vec3 normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    vec4 diffuse = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < lightcount; i++)
    {
        //Adding the diffuse term multiplied by gl_Color for each light.
        //There should be no color (0,0,0,0) if the lights are null
        diffuse += lightdifs[i] * max(dot(normal, normalize(lightdirs[i])), 0.0) * gl_Color;
    }

    gl_FrontColor = diffuse;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

My fragment shader (contained in "dirlight.fs")

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
}
```

Excerpt from initialization in C++ main...

```
//class program manages shaders
Program shaders = Program();
//attach a vertex shader, compiled from source in dirlight.vs
shaders.addShaderFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "dirlight.vs");
//attach a fragment shader compiled from source in dirlight.fs
shaders.addShaderFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "dirlight.fs");
//link program
shaders.link();
//use program
shaders.use();

//Program::getUniformLoc(const char* name) grabs the location
//of the uniform specified
GLint sTime = shaders.getUniformLoc("time");
GLint lightcount = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightcount");
GLint lightdir = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightdirs");
GLint lightdif = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightdifs");
GLint lightamb = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightambs");

glUniform1i(lightcount, 2);
GLfloat lightdirs[] = {-1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f,
                       1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f};
glUniform4fv(lightdir, 2, lightdirs);
GLfloat lightdifs[] = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f,
                       1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
glUniform4fv(lightdif, 2, lightdifs);
glUniform4f(lightamb, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.f);
```

Excerpt from main loop in C++ main...

```
glUniform1f(sTime, newTime);
//This should cause the light directions to rotate around the origin
GLfloat lightdirs[] = {sinf(newTime * 2.f), 1.f, cosf(newTime * 2.0f), 1.f,
                       cosf(newTime * 2.f), 1.f, sinf(newTime * 2.0f), 1.f};
glUniform4fv(lightdir, 2, lightdirs);
```

Comment: I take it, you're creating the program object _after_ you created and made current a OpenGL render context, and initialized the extensions thereafter, too? So far Programm::addShaderFile is opaque, having the sourcecode of that, and Program::getUniformLoc may help.

Comment: Next time you ask GLSL question, specify OpenGL version and GLSL version. You have not provided source code for shader compilation/loading routines, so by Murphy's law I will assume there is no error checking at all. You should check shader compile status and program link status using corresponding API functions - glGetProgramiv and glGetShaderiv. Also extract and read info log for shader and program after link/compilation. For debug purposes you could add glGetError after every OpenGL call - shader related or not.

Comment: As stated in my question, I have already confirmed that there are ZERO problems with the way I'm loading the shaders, by loading other custom shaders. The problem is either with the shader itself or with the way I handle uniforms/attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uniform vec4 lightdirs[];
```

That is not legal GLSL. I can't explain why your compiler allows compiling (I'm guessing it's an NVIDIA compiler, right? That of course assumes that you are checking the compilation/link status), but uniform arrays *must* have a length defined explicitly within the shader. If you want to have variable length arrays, you have to pick a maximum length and bake it into the shader. The shader can read fewer values (a length based on a uniform you pass in), but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks! Setting a max length worked! Awsome. Wierd that it didn't give me any compile errors though. I don't know if it's an NVIDIA compiler, but I have an NVIDIA graphics card, if that's what compiles it...

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre Yes, the GLSL compiler is part of the graphics driver.

Comment: Since you're on NVidia, have a look at [NVEmulate](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvemulate). Among others, it allows you to set the GLSL compiler to "strict" so it stops accepting CUDA constructs. There are other interesting features there.